# Filtering an image using GPUImageFilterGroup returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, gpuimage

I have subclassed GPUImageFilterGroup into a class called SEFilter like this.

SEFilter.h File

```
#import "GPUImageFilterGroup.h"
#import "GPUImagePicture.h"
#import "GPUImageLookupFilter.h"
#import "GPUImageBilateralFilter.h"

@class GPUImagePicture;

@interface SEFilter : GPUImageFilterGroup
{
    GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *filterName;

-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image filterName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

SEFiletr.m File

```
#import "SEFilter.h"
#import "GPUImageVignetteFilter.h"
#import "GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter.h"
#import "GPUImageOpacityFilter.h"

@implementation SEFilter

-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image filterName:(NSString *)name {
    if (!(self = [super init]))
    {
        return nil;
    }
    self.filterName = name;
    lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];

    [lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter atTextureLocation:1];
    [lookupImageSource processImage];

    //Clean the face
    GPUImageBilateralFilter *faceCleanFilter = [[GPUImageBilateralFilter alloc] init];
    faceCleanFilter.distanceNormalizationFactor = 20.0;

//  GPUImageVignetteFilter *vignetteFilter = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init];
//  vignetteFilter.vignetteStart = 0.5;

    GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter *testFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter alloc] init];
    testFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 3.0f;
    testFilter.excludeCircleRadius = 0.6;
    testFilter.excludeBlurSize = 0.5;

    [self addFilter:faceCleanFilter];
    [self addFilter:lookupFilter];
    [self addFilter:testFilter];

    [faceCleanFilter addTarget:lookupFilter];
    [lookupFilter addTarget:testFilter];


    self.initialFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:faceCleanFilter];
    self.terminalFilter = testFilter;

    return self;
}

@end
```

To create a new filter I just initialize this class with a lookup image. This mechanism is working for filtering live video. But when I try to filter a UIImage the filtered image becomes nil. I use the following code to filter a UIImage

```
let filter = SEFilter(image: UIImage(named: "test"), filterName: "Test")
    if let theImage = image {
        let stillImage = GPUImagePicture(image: theImage)
        filter.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
        stillImage.addTarget(filter)
        stillImage.processImage()

        let filteredImage = filter.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
        imageView.image = filteredImage
    }
```

Here, filter is an instance of SEFilter. imageView.image is nil after this function. I am using swift and objective c in my project. So, some of the code is in swift and some in objective c. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.